# Alternative to LinearLayouts' layout_weight attribute?

Tags: android

I need a View to hold a number of TextViews, and the exact number I will not know unfortunately. I need the TextViews to sort of stack either under each other or right next to each other (imagine Tetris, but with just rectangles or squares). The way I have tried thinking about it is using LinearLayout to hold them either horizontally or vertically. I then use their weights to stretch them appropriately if they are next to each other. Otherwise, I use a vertical orientation. Problem is the performance with nested LinearLayouts with more complicated stacks. I thought about using RelativeLayout, but that wouldn't work because I need the TextViews to not overlap. So like if they are next to each other, they need to each take enough space evenly. With layout_weight it works great. I was hoping someone had any idea on how to make this work right/alternative.

Heres an example that is giving me a warning (only a simple example of what I am doing programmatically):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World 1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World 3"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World 4"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World 2"
        android:background="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried it with RelativeLayout by the way, but one of the TextView's needs to be a set size, but I need them to take space evenly. I won't know specific sizes. Measuring the screen width and dividing it that way is also both clunky and not precise. I appreciate anybodies input.

**Edit:** So I've been thinking about it some more and thought of a solution using RelativeLayout. There is a nice example in the Android [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html), but the only problem is one of the Views needs to be a set size so the other one could stretch. But if there is a way to allow all of them not to have a set size, that could work too, so then they can stretch. Anyone tried doing that at some point?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say that you don't know how many `TextViews` there will be but then show an XML layout file. If you don't know how many there will be then you'll have to create your layout programatically.

Comment: @Squonk I added "Heres an example that is giving me a warning". I decided to test it out in a simple version compared to doing it with my more complicated version programmatically.Again, its an example.

Comment: What about a table layout? They are pretty easy to create in code, and seems like it could do what you want

Comment: @Jameo I have thought about that, but the issue is having the TableRow View as well. Like 2 Views to hold one View. Not very efficient. But I Have not used it very often. Any hints would be appreciated if you have a very efficient way in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what your final use case looks like, so I don't know if this will completely solve your problem, but you might take a look at `TableLayout` ([docs link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html)).  It's based on `LinearLayout` so items can still be defined to evenly occupy a given space, but it allows you to define your positions and spans in terms of rows and columns.

So, for instance, your example code would look like:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >
    <!-- Wrap all items in a given row in a TableRow -->
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="Hello World 1"
            android:background="#000000"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="Hello World 3"
            android:background="#000000"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="Hello World 4"
            android:background="#000000"/>
    </TableRow>
    <!-- If a child occupies an entire row, it can be by itself -->
    <TextView
        android:text="Hello World 2"
        android:background="#000000"/>
</TableLayout>
```

You can also use the `android:layout_column` and `android:layout_span` attributes to define exactly which column an item should be in, and how many columns it should occupy.  Also note that `TableLayout` and `TableRow` have basically ignore any layout params applied and use very specific (documented) parameters, so adding them to your code will only confuse what is actually going on.  Of course, this can all be built programmatically as well as in XML.

If this does not provide the flexibility you need, I would then recommend creating your own custom layout that either extends or is based on `LinearLayout`.  The mechanism is uses to measure children with weight is not that complex, and then you can override how each child is placed after measurement.  Here is a [source link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/LinearLayout.java) to `LinearLayout` if you want to see how the platform does these things.

Comment: Yea I was worried I would need to create my own custom View, but I have no idea how to do it it regards to extending LinearLayout. Anyways, I really appreciate your example code. I just tried it out and it works nicely for horizontal views within the TableRow :) In terms of efficiency, that extra TableRow shouldn't be an issue right? Oh and do you by any chance know a great tutorial on creating custom views? If not its fine, you've been a big help either way!

Comment: The performance should be slightly better than a nested layout with weights since it is an optimized case, though probably not as much as going fully custom since you can pull out all the code that doesn't do exactly what your application needs.  For doing a custom layout, you might look at Romain Guy's Devoxx session from a few years ago.  He live codes a FlowLayout implementation in the video: http://www.parleys.com/#st=5&id=2191&sl=0

Comment: WOW!! I would have never found that. I really appreciate your time and input. It really gave me enough to figure out my best options. Wish I could do more than just up-vote and accept. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** As we know the percent support library is deprecated from API level 26. `ConstraintLayout` is the new way to achieve the same flat xml structure.

[**Updated Github Project**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vuL3.png)

**Updated Samples:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fifty_thirty"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ffff8800"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/fifty_fifty_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ffff5566"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/fifty_fifty_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/fifty_thirty"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fifty_thirty"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Deprecated**

**update:** We can use android support library for the same.

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.0'
```

Consider this demo for dividing the screen into 50-50 percent.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fifty_huntv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ff7acfff"
        android:text="20% - 50%"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fifty_huntv"
        android:background="#ffff5566"
        android:text="80%-50%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="80%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image: percent support library demo]

[Demo HERE!!!](http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-percent-support-lib-sample.html)

[GitHub Project HERE!!!](https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/android-percent-layout-sample)